# Need to Fetch the radio button value, but in the console that is highlighting only by ": :before" i am not able to fetch that

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I wanted to fetch the Radio button is selected or not, but not able to fetch that property, because that is highlighting ": :before" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pLb0.png)
Please can you help how to fetch the exact property.

Comment: Could you paste the image as code please.. Please share the website link also, if it's ok to share here

Answer (score 0):

You should select the `input element` above `::before` or I think you should select the outer `label element` to check that form in Selenium.